# Calling controller with ajax in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to fetch data from a controller and update my view using ajax.

This is my controller:

```
public class PatientController
{
    DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();
    public JsonResult GetPatientFromCpr()
    {
        var patient = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Cpr == "2410911615");
        return new JsonResult() { Data = patient, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    } 
}
```

And this is my ajax call:

```
    function getPatient() {
    cpr2 = $("#cpr-first").val() + $("#cpr-last").val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: '/Patient/GetPatientFromCpr',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function () {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        },
    });
}
```

When i call the function i always get the error alert.

```
GET http://localhost:51140/Patient/GetPatientFromCpr 404 (Not Found)
```

Can someone point out what's wrong?

(EDIT)
I now get a new error after adding ": Controller"

`GET http://localhost:51140/Patient/GetPatientFromCpr 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: where is the type , add type:"Get" after url call

Comment: The url looks correct. What happens when you enter it in the address bar and navigate to it? Are your using areas?

Comment: @SrinivasR, The default is 'GET'

Comment: Can u please share the routes

Comment: @StephenMuecke I get 404 when entering it. Areas?

Comment: @Shu Routes?
I'm really new to this, so I apologize if I have missend something simple.

Comment: Remove dataType: 'json' and try again, working fine in my code with removal of dataType

Comment: add the request Type in tha AJAX request like type:"POST"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'PatientController' is not a `Controller` (it does not inherit from `Controller`)

```
public class PatientController : Controller
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Wow i'm stupid. Thanks, but it didn't fix my error (Well it must have fixed something)

Comment: Are you saying your still getting a `404 Not Found`?

Comment: Ahh no you are right..

    GET http://localhost:51140/Patient/GetPatientFromCpr 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Then that means your server code is throwing an exception - you need to debug your code (and you can use your browser tools to inspect the response and the error details (Network Tab). And please undo your edit to the question - or I will - you cant just change the question based on a correct answer (in makes my answer pointless)

Comment: I already did it :). This answers you question and if your getting a different error, then that needs to be a new question. But debugging your code should solve it.

Comment: add the request Type in tha AJAX request like type:"POST", and also Remove dataType: 'json' and try again, working fine in my code with removal of dataType

Comment: @Smit. NO! OP is sending back a `JsonResult` so it needs to be `dataType: 'json'` and its a GET method so it needs to be `type: 'get'` but that is the default so it can be omitted.

Comment: @Smit, Read OP's comments. My answer solved the problem (none of your changes are necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Inherit you `PatientController` with `Base Controller Class`

```
public class PatientController : Controller
```

In controller

```
 public JsonResult GetPatientFromCpr()
    {
        var patient = db.Patients.where(p => p.Cpr == "2410911615").FirstOrDefault();
        return new JsonResult() { Data = patient, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

And Specify the type of ajax calling

```
type: "POST" or type: "GET" ....
```

This will help you to fix error

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it has already been replied. I now get a new error (500).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, may be this works..!!

View:

```
function getPatient() {
    cpr2 = $("#cpr-first").val() + $("#cpr-last").val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: '/Patient/GetPatientFromCpr',
        //dataType: 'json',
        type:"POST", // GET or POST
        success: function () {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        },
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public class PatientController : Controller
{
   ....
}
```